# Optional object with generic in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Not sure how to specify my question. So here's an example:

```
final class MyClass<T: MyProtocol>: NSObject {
    init(something: Something<[T]>) { ... }
}
```

This object (`MyClass`) will be inside `ViewController`

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    //Should be optional, because I will assing myObject in prepareForSegue
    //And I will initialize MyClass with different Objects,
    //that implement MyProtocol
    var myObject: MyClass?
}
```

But I must specify `MyClass` generic type, but I will not know during init. 
So my question would be is it possible to have an optional object with generic that will be specified later in life cycle?

**EDIT.** I think it's impossible to achieve what I want, without specifying Generic type in the init.

Comment: Not sure if I right understood. Would this work for you: `var myObject: MyProtocol?` ?

Comment: No, this does not work, Xcode complains that MyClass is not specifying its generic type. If I would know my generic type, I could write `var myObject: MyClass<SomeGenericType>?` where `SomeGenericType` implements `MyProtocol`. 

My problem is that I don't know generic type at VC init, I know it only after it's being passed via segue.

Comment: I think you do not actually need a generic type, but maybe I get it wrong.

Comment: I've currently implemented this without Generics but later, I have to cast objects as `MyProtocol` and with Generic I could avoid it. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is solvable with type-erasers, but how to implement it depends a lot on how `MyClass` and `Something` are used. Having this many generics and protocols intermixing really raises the question of whether it's over-engineered or if `MyViewController` is doing too much work. (Cocoa limitations due to storyboards do create some important restrictions here, so you may be doing everything right and still get into this box; but you should always carefully ask if you're really using all the generics and protocols or could get rid of some of them.) `Something<[T]>` is particularly suspicious IMO.

Comment: (You've done a fine job narrowing the question, BTW. It's just that the answer is a bit dependent on your situation, so a little more info would help so I don't write every possible way you could build it. :D) The short answer is: you probably want to build an `AnyMyProtocol` that `MyClass` uses. See http://robnapier.net/erasure for an example of building `Any...` types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a variable that is both a class and a protocol. This is only possible in Swift 4 with the current syntax:

```
let myObject: MyClass & MyProtocol
```

A workaround could be a use of NSObject (Because your class inherits the NSObject) Then if you need the class properties/functions, you can cast it back to your class:

```
var myObject: NSObject?
(myObject as? MyClass<YourGenericT>).someFunctionDeclaredInMyClass()
```

Comment: Not really, I don't want to specify Generic type of `MyClass` object in the init. In this theoretical example I would push `MyViewController` via segue, and would specify `myObject` in `prepareForSegue`, but I may push `myObject` where `T` is different although implements `MyProtocol`. I am not sure how to explain it clearer. Anyways, I am starting to think it is impossible.

Comment: You could define `myObject` as an optional `MyProtocol`. But why do you want an object that could be anything? The only thing they have in common is `MyProtocol` so you should define your variable as `MyProtocol`